# What is the definition of an active member?

Tags: support, badges

The description of the "Yearling" badge reads

> *Active* member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation.

My question is, what does it mean being an active member? Is it visiting the site every day?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The phrase "*Active member for a year*" is irrelevant to the implementation of the badge, and just describes the general idea of what the badge is supposed to be rewarding. The other part about "*earning at least 200 reputation*" is misleading, because the rule is:

> On the $n$th anniversary of your joining a given SE site, if your reputation is greater than or equal to $200n$, then you are awarded a Yearling badge on that site.

So if you earn $1000$ reputation in your first year, you could never visit the site again and still get the Yearling badge each anniversary of your joining the site, until the 6th anniversary.

Sources: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/161783), [Details on how the Yearling badge works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43240/161783)

Answer (score 6):

Copy/pasted from [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/148069):

> #### Yearling
>
> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Have `reputation ≥ (number of years as an active user) × 200`
>
>   - The script that awards this badge only runs on the anniversary of you joining the site
>   - If you do not qualify for Yearling on an anniversary, but do meet it before your next anniversary, the badge **will** be awarded
>
>     - Example: A user who earns 190 rep in his first year will not be awarded Yearling on his first anniversary. If the user earns 40 more
>         rep exactly one month after the first anniversary, the Yearling badge
>         will be awarded the next time the badge script runs. This is because
>         (190 + 40 = 230 rep) > (200 rep / year × 1 1/12<sup>th</sup> years =
>         217 rep)
>   - The badge used to require only `years × 100` rep; this was [changed after the account association bonus was
>       implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32626)