# Yearling badge was not awarded?

Tags: support, badges

This is my first post on Meta and my second interaction ever, but on the main site I have been somewhat active for a full year now. I love this site, so many insightful answers and intriguing questions :D

Anyway, I was somewhat looking forward for the Yearling badge, and after looking up "Yearling" I now know how it works: see [What is the definition of an active member?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10797/1104384)

However, I did not get that badge, even though today is now my 366th day and 3900 or so rep points should be overkill for that badge... I don't really mind it that much though, it's just a badge after all. However I still wrote this post to see if it's a normal occurence with the Yearling script (maybe there's something else to it?) or if it's a rare bug.

(I don't know what tags to use so feel free to re-tag.)

Comment: According to your profile you started at MSE on 7 October 2022 at about 15:40 (UTC). So your Yearling badge should be arriving in a few hours. StackExchange is quite pedantic when it comes to dates and times and every second counts.

Comment: @PeterPhipps Oh I see, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @PeterPhipps I just got my Yearling badges just now. I guess my post was useless... but thank you.

Comment: Enjoy your badge; there'll be another one along next year! Please change your question tag from `bug` to `support`. The question may help people in future so isn't a waste.

Comment: @PeterPhipps maybe convert your comment into an answer to be more clear to future visitors?

Comment: I don't mind explained downvotes at all, but I don't quite know what else I could have done here: I thought there was a problem, I stated my problem, and I presented some personal research on my problem even if it's light. Though I do agree that it's not the most interesting question since it was solved by just waiting a few hours for the "not-actually-a-problem" problem to be fixed, that is totally fair. I also didn't mean to boast about my reputation points or anything, it was just to show that I've fulfilled the requirements for the badge, I apologise if it was taken the wrong way.

Comment: @BrunoB Many people downvote "oopsies" questions since they aren't 'real' bugs/problems, a practice I don't necessarily agree with, especially if the question isn't a duplicate (it's still useful in case someone else has a similar "oopsie" in the future.)